# R - Making a ggplot while using survey package

Tags: r, ggplot2, survey

I am stuck with a real problem.
My dataset comes from a survey and to make it  usable to find statistics about the whole French population, I must weight it with weights.

For this purpose, I used the **survey** package, but the syntax is not really easy to use with R.

Is there a way to use ggplot while having weights?

To explain it a bit better, here is my dataset:

```
head(df)

Id  Weight   Var1
1     30        0
2     12.4      0
3     68.2      1
```

So my individual 1 accounts for 30 people in the French population.
I create a `df_weighted` dataset using the survey package.

How can I use ggplot now? df_weighted is a list!
I did something like this to try to escape the list problem but I did not work at all...

```
df_weighted_ggplot$var1 <- svytable(~var1, df_weighted)
df_weighted_ggplot$var_fill <- svytable(~var_fill, df_weighted)


ggplot(df_weighted_ggplot, aes(fill = var_fill , x =var1)) + geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

I received this predictable error:
`` Erreur : `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a list ``

Do you know any other package which should help me? But I read many forums and it seems to be the most helpful...

Comment: Is the structure of `df_weighted` a list of same-length vectors? (check `str(df_weighted)`) If so, `as.data.frame(df_weighted)` may solve the problem.

Comment: I cannot use ```as.data.frame(df_weighted)```. Here is the error message : ```Error in as.data.frame.default(df_weighted) :   cannot coerce class ‘c("survey.design2", "survey.design")’ to a data.frame```

Comment: Can you include some code for how to transform `df` into `df_weighted`?  This will make it easier to examine, since this sounds like it's actually not a `ggplot2` question.

Comment: if `data.frame(...)` doesn't work, maybe `unlist()` your `svytable(...)` or instead use `coef( svytotal(...))` to get the same weighted counts as a numeric vector?

Comment: One approach is to use the srvyr package, which provides a tidyverse-style wrapper for survey: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/srvyr/vignettes/srvyr-vs-survey.html